# Driving in the EU on UK licence

Tags: united-kingdom, eu, driving-license, residency

I wasn't born in the UK, but I lived there for 4 years, and I have a full UK driving license which expires in 2025. I recently moved to Pakistan. If I travel to another European or Scandinavian country on holidays, can I drive a car there on this license? What if I live permanently in a European or Scandinavian country?

Answer (score 1):

From Gov.UK Website:

Driving in Europe

You can use your Great Britain (GB) or Northern Ireland driving licence in all [EU or European Economic Area (EEA) countries](https://www.gov.uk/eu-eea) , and Switzerland.

For rules in other European countries check with a motoring organisation like the [AA](http://www.theaa.com/motoring_advice/overseas/countrybycountry.html) or the [RAC](http://www.rac.co.uk/driving-abroad/).

So obviously yes, you can!

Comment: It's not obvious. Is the driving license validity contingent on residency in the UK?

Comment: No, it shouldn't..

Answer (score 1):

If you are visiting an EU country, you can use your UK license.

If you move permanently to another EU country, you can use your UK license for some time. The rules regarding exactly how long are a bit complicated but if you have a 10-year license, you should be able to use it until it expires. After that, you should be able to get a local license relatively easily on the basis of your UK driving exam.

Your citizenship and current residence outside of the European Union do not matter, as long as you obtained your license in the EU.

None of this applies if you obtained your UK license in exchange for another, non-EU, license.